# Declare a variable to be instantiate at a class level, and used inside the class functions

Tags: c++, qt

Let's say I have this class. How should I declare/instantiate the image object so that I can use it with all functions without the need to pass it as an argument?

`view.h`

```
class AAView : public QGraphicsView {

public:
    explicit AAView();
    QGraphicsScene* currentScene;
    QImage image;
};
```

`view.cpp`

```
AAView::AAView() {

    int sizeX = 1280;
    int sizeY = 720;

    image(sizeX, sizeY, QImage::Format_RGB32);
}

void AAView::drawPoint(int x, int y) {
    image.setPixel(x, y, qRgb(255, 255, 100));
}
```

I got this error:

```
error: no match for call to '(QImage) (int&, int&, QImage::Format)'
     image(sizeX, sizeY, QImage::Format_RGB32);
```

But by removing the image variable from the header, this error disappeared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be trying to call the `QImage` constructor for `image`, but that's not the correct syntax.

You can replace it with the following line inside the constructor

```
image = QImage(sizeX, sizeY, QImage::Format_RGB32);
```

or preferably construct it in a member initializer list

```
AAView::AAView() : image(1280, 720, QImage::Format_RGB32) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to construct `image` in that way (or any other), then the best way is to do it in the member initialiser list:

```
AAView::AAView() : image (1280, 720, QImage::Format_RGB32) { ...
```